# Timesheet management Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

So my organization just got an enterprise-wide migration to office 365. With this we got Office 365 and sharepoint.

I'd like to implement a simple TimeSheet management system. Where employees can go in and enter their hours and have that submission routed to an approver or manager.

I understand that MS Project is the right tool for this but we do not have that. I know that I can route approvals etc through Flow but what's the best way to set up the time sheet projects and have users come in and enter their hours?

As an aside, I'd like to spawn a new project site (based off a template site) every-time a new project is added to the list of projects. Is this possible, if so, how?

I understand that these are extremely broad questions but any nudge in the right direction will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the time management solution I will recommend that you take a look at Powerapps as this will give you the simplicity of the Sharepoint list and yet the option to provide a flexible user interface.
Regarding the projekt sites I'll point to either Teams or modern SharePoint site scripts.